# Problems with coordinates after calling robot.mouseMove(x,y)

Tags: java, processing, mousemove, mouse-position

currently I'm working on a [Processing](https://processing.org/) application that moves the mouse pointer around the screen to draw some circles. The final scope is to automate circle drawing in paint (or other apps) and to do so I have to press the left mouse, move the mouse then release the button. The problem is that when I call the `robot.mouseMove(x,y)` function the successive readings of the coordinates on screen are all messed up.

To debug the problem I've tested if the origin(I've a 1920x1080 dispaly) is correct at the start of the program. Using `mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` and then `println("X: " + mouse.x + "Y: " + mouse.y);` returns the expected values of both X and Y.
The problem comes after I decide to move my cursor to ANY other position after that. For example: `robot.mouseMove(960,540);` (center screen) make the mouse move but not in the correct position, infact the printed coordinates are X= 1199 ~ 1200 and Y= 674.

Here is a snippet of code where I move the mouse:

```
r.mouseMove(startcircleX, startcircleY); //starting coordinates for the circle
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); //series of keypress to activate the pen tool
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK); //left mouse press
for (step = 0; step <= maxstep; step++) { //number of points in the circle move
    float t = 2 * PI * step / maxstep; //360° 
    int X = (int)(circleX + radius * cos(t)); //here I calculate the coordiantes for the movements
    int Y = (int)(circleY + radius * sin(t));
    r.mouseMove(X, Y);
}
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); //left mouse release
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

I'm expecting that the grid of coordinates remain "constant" even if I move the mouse, otherwise what's the point? Maybe I'm missing something or it's just a silly mistake but I can't get out of it...
If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: When you measured, were you updating the pointer info afterwards? The docs say PointerInfo doesn't update as the mouse moves.

Comment: Yes, I update the pointer info(it's missing in the code that I provided...my bad)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: `void draw() {
  Point mouse;
  println(displayWidth + " " + displayHeight);//1920x1080
  r.mouseMove(0,0);
  mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
  println( "X=" + mouse.x + " Y=" + mouse.y );
  delay(2000);
  r.mouseMove((displayWidth/2),(displayHeight/2)); //960x540
  mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
  println( "X=" + mouse.x + " Y=" + mouse.y );
  delay(2000);
  r.mouseMove((displayWidth/3), (displayHeight/3)); //640x 360
  mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
  println( "X=" + mouse.x + " Y=" + mouse.y );
  delay(2000);
}`

Comment: With this code you'll see that the coordinates after 0x0 are incorrect, both in the cursor position(not at center but a little bit on the right) and the values on the terminal aren't the one that we specify on the move comand